# numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U43'), dtype('<U12')) -> None

Tags: python, numpy

my code

```
np.loadtxt(open(datapath+'\\'+sub[i]+'\\'+task[j]+".csv","rb"),dtype="str",delimiter=",")
```

then error was given:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U43'), dtype('<U12')) -> None
```

how to solve it?

Comment: what have you done to debug this?  to isolate where the problem occurs?  Does the filename construction work by itself?

Comment: I suspect `sub` and `task` are `numpy` arrays of strings.  This kind of string concatenation works with lists of strings, not arrays.